# ASP.NET CORE OnActionExecuting Not Firing Remotely

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET **CORE** WebApi project that has a base controller class that overrides the **OnActionExecuting** method to perform work (what work doesn’t matter for this post).

The OnActionExecuting method fires when I’m running locally (VS Pro 2017 - localhost - IIS Express) but fails to fire when I publish a build with the same code to a server environment (Windows Server 2016 Standard - IIS 10.0.14393.0).

Any ideas why the OnActionExecuting method is called on localhost but fails to fire on a remote host running IIS?

Here’s the code:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionExecutingContext)
    {
            //This method fires on localhost but not on remote server (IIS)

            //call into base method
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionExecutingContext);

            //validate http context exists
            if (HttpContext == null)
                throw new Exception("The HttpContext should not be null.");

            //do other work...
    }
}
```

Comment: It is strange. Could you host in local IIS and debug it?

Comment: this article may be of use: https://andrewlock.net/using-an-iactionfilter-to-read-action-method-parameter-values-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

Issue is not because of a actionfilters, i had same issue because of request body issues in IIS express.

```
before reading request body need to EnableBuffering and after that need add Body.Position = 0

Solution 1:



context.Request.EnableBuffering();

    // Leave the body open so the next middleware can read it.
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(
        context.Request.Body,
        encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
        detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false,
        bufferSize: bufferSize,
        leaveOpen: true))
    {
        var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        // Do some processing with body…

        // Reset the request body stream position so the next middleware can read it
        context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
    }

solution 2:

 private async Task<string> FormatRequest(HttpRequest request)
        {
            request.EnableBuffering();
            var requestBody = await ReadBodyFromPipeReader(request.BodyReader);
            request.Body.Position = 0;
            return requestBody;
        }

 private async Task<string> ReadBodyFromPipeReader(PipeReader reader)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while (true)
            {
                // await some data being available
                ReadResult read = await reader.ReadAsync();
                ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer = read.Buffer;
                // check whether we've reached the end
                // and processed everything
                if (buffer.IsEmpty && read.IsCompleted)
                    break; // exit loop

                // process what we received
                foreach (var segment in buffer)
                {
                    string asciString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                        segment.Span);
                    stringBuilder.Append(asciString);
                }
                // tell the pipe that we used everything   
                reader.AdvanceTo(buffer.Start, buffer.End);
                if (read.IsCompleted)
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
            return Convert.ToString(stringBuilder);
        }
```